# Typescript extend React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

*@tl;dr*
I want to extend a React Component without using HOC / Providers in Typescript

---

OK, so here's the deal...
At my work place we used to work with Vue and plain JS... then we decided to migrate to React with Typescript...

**Tecnologies we use**:
- React
- Typescript
- Redux
- Redux-Saga

The thing is, back in Vue, we could declare something like:

```
Vue.use(Auth)
```

and on every .vue file, inside the script tag we could call something like:

```
this.$auth
```

and have access to authorizatin methods.

What I want to do is... create an extension of ReactComponent where I already created some methods that most of my Component will use... something like:

- auth // Check if user is authenticated, and if so, get the User Info
- route // Give me the current route, with query params, redirects, etc...
  Those were the only two I could think off here now.

I want to have in my .ts file something like this:

```
interface MyProps {
    route: any // don't remember the correct Type
}

class MyComponent<T,S = {},SS = {}> extends React.Component<T,S,SS> {
    $route = () => {
        this.props.route
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

and have it being called in my application like this:

```
inteface AnotherProps {

}

class AnotherComponent extends MyComponent<AnotherProps> {
    render() {
        if(this.$route().location.pathname == "/") {
            return <div>Root</div>
        } else {
            return <div>Not Root</div>
        }
    }
}
```

## What I have tried so far

### HOC (High Order Components)

I could achieve what I want using HOC, but the thing is... if possible, I would like 2 things.

- To have this new properties being store at **this** and not **this.props**, and if that's possible using HOC, i don't know how
- With HOC, I would also need to import the base Props, something like this:

```
import BaseProps from Outterspace;

inteface AnotherProps extends BaseProps{

}
```

and I want the logic inside the **MyComponent** and **AnotherComponent** to be as independent to each other as possible...

### Providers

Same as HOC, I would need to pass the properties I want as props, and would need to extend my props interface.

[EDIT]

### Decorators

Someone said in the comments that I could try using Decoratos, and while I did read the docs and it sounded promising... the last line of the Docs kinda worries me..

**NOTE  Decorator metadata is an experimental feature and may introduce breaking changes in future releases.**

Thank you so much for reading this far ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript then you can create decorators.

You can call the decorator on top of your class and add the property.

```js
@YourAuthDecorator({
  'propertiesForconfiguration': 'value'
})
export class ReactClass extends ReactComponent {}
```

Example:

```js
function abc() {
  return {};
}

export function Auth() {
  console.log("-- decorator function invoked --");
  return function (constructor: Function){
    console.log(constructor, 'called');
    constructor.prototype.$auth = abc();
  }
}

class Sample {
  public prop = 'sample'
}

@Auth()
export class Content extends Sample {

}

export const a = new Content();
```

It will be the decorator's functionality to append various properties the to **this** instance providing you access to various functions/properties like **auth**

You can read more about decorators here.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: So I'm reading the docs and there's some very complex stuff like reflect.metadata and such...
How exactly would you suggest I use this when I want to let **MyComponent** handle whatever store update?

Comment: Also... the last line of the doc's kinda worries me:

**NOTE  Decorator metadata is an experimental feature and may introduce breaking changes in future releases.**

Comment: Angular is a major framework written on top of typescript which heavily uses decorators for the entire framework.

Comment: but I cant change from React :c

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example that will add the $auth property to the class prototype at runtime.